# Examples of Wizard controls

Tags: user-interface, controls, components, wizard

I'm creating a Wizard control (in Flex) and wanted to look at some examples of good Wizard controls in .NET, Java or other languages.

I'm especially interested in situations where next/prev steps are determined by the input of the current step. For instance, choosing one of several options in the start screen will lead you to different screens, etc

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Wizard Control for .Net on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx).

For programming the behavior of the wizard , you might also find the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For UI samples, there are lots of these.

[Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Wizards):

[image: Eclipse Wizard]

[Apple](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGInstallationsUpdates/chapter_10_section_4.html) (these are called Assistants in Apple parlance):

[Apple Assistant http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/art/iu_setupassistant.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/art/iu_setupassistant.jpg)

[Wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511302.aspx) in Windows:

[Aero Wizard http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511302.wizards01(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511302.wizards01(en-us,MSDN.10).png)

For implementation details, see Fowler's [Application Controller](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa511302.wizards01(en-us,MSDN.10).png)